# Why doesn't the built-in implementation of LinkedList.add() in Java add elements to ashallow copy of the LinkedList, but custom implementation adds?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

In example below, in "main" when after cloning LinkedList l1 to l2, when I add element to l2, I do not get 300 in l1.

However, in the the method "addTwoLists" when I use custom implementation, adding any element to "rohit" adds it to "first" as well.

```
package hackerrank;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Node1 implements Cloneable{
    int data;
    Node1 next;
    Node1(int x){
        this.data=x;
        this.next=null;
    }
    Node1 (){
        
    }
    protected Node1 clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Node1) super.clone();
    }
    
}
public class MS_linkedlist_copy {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
         LinkedList<AtomicInteger> l1 = new LinkedList<>();
            l1.add(new AtomicInteger(100));
            l1.add(new AtomicInteger(200));

            LinkedList<AtomicInteger> l2 = (LinkedList) l1.clone();
            l2.add(new AtomicInteger(300));

            System.out.println(l1);
            System.out.println(l2);

            // change element on first list
            l1.get(0).incrementAndGet();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("After change internal state of first element");
            System.out.println(l1);
            System.out.println(l2);
            
            
            
        Node1 first = new Node1(1);
        Node1 second = new Node1(2);
        first.next= second;
        
        
        Node1 third = new Node1(3);
        Node1 fourth = new Node1(4);
        third.next=fourth;
        
        addTwoLists(first, third);
    }
    
    static Node1 reverse(Node1 head){
        Node1 prev =null;
        while(head!=null){
            Node1 next_node = head.next;
            head.next = prev;
            prev=head;
            head=next_node;
        }
        return prev;
    }
    //
    static Node1 addTwoLists(Node1 first, Node1 second){
        System.out.println(first.data);
        Node1 rohit = null;
        try {
            rohit = (Node1)first.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rohit.data=1000;
        rohit.next.data=1000;
        System.out.println(first.data);
        System.out.println(rohit.data);
        
        Node1 rohit2= rohit;
        while(rohit.next!=null) {
            rohit= rohit.next;
        }
        Node1 rohit_add = new Node1(2000);
        rohit.next = rohit_add;
        System.out.println(first.data);
        System.out.println(rohit2.data);
//      rohit = first;
//        rohit= reverse(rohit); 
//        reverse(second);
//        System.out.println(first.data);
//        System.out.println(rohit.data);
        
        
        return null;
        }

}
```

I tried to add elements to a shallow copy in custom, which got added to main list successfully. However, after trying to add elements to shallow copy of built-in LinkedList, the elements are not added to original list. I am trying to understand what is going on in the built-in LinkedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `LinkedList.clone` also copies *all the nodes in the entire linked list*, whereas your `Node1.clone` only copies that one node, and not any of the nodes linked to it.

You can find an implementation of `LinkedList.clone` [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L1024),

```
public Object clone() {
    LinkedList<E> clone = superClone();

    // Put clone into "virgin" state
    clone.first = clone.last = null;
    clone.size = 0;
    clone.modCount = 0;

    // Initialize clone with our elements
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        clone.add(x.item);

    return clone;
}
```

Notice that it calls `add` on the cloned list (called `clone` here) in the loop. Each call to `add` creates a new linked list node.

Note that this is still a shallow copy, in the sense that the data in the nodes are not cloned. For example, if the lists stores `String` objects, no new strings are created.

So after cloning, you actually get two "chains" with the builtin `LinkedList`:

```
O-O-O
O-O-O
```

whereas with your `Node1`, since only one node is cloned, you get something like this:

```
 first -> O
           \
            -O-O
           /
rohit2 -> O
```

The two "heads" of the lists share the same "end", so adding an element to the end of the list adds it to both lists.

You can rewrite your `clone` so that it copies all the nodes. One simple way is to do it recursively:

```
protected Node1 clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Node1 newNode = new Node1(this.data);
    if (next != null) {
        newNode.next = next.clone();
    }
    return newNode;
}
```